# Accidently removed networking services

Tags: networking, 20.04

I was having problems upgrading from 20.04 to 20.10. I read on SO that someone fixed the issue by uninstalling `libssh-4`, so I ran `sudo apt remove libssh-4`. To my horror a lot of things were removed, including Libre Office, network services and many other things.

The prompt showed a list of what would be removed, but it didnt include network services, eg:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libiw30 libkeybinder0 libnghttp2-14 librtmp1 libwnck-common libwnck22 libxres1 lxpanel-data
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

I now have no wifi or ethernet capabilities. And I dont have a usb stick present with which to try re-installing.

Is there way I can reinstall networking capabilities?

Comment: "*To my horror a lot of things were removed*" ... When you run this command, it generates a summary of what will happen if you hit `Y` and `Enter`.  My intention isn't to rub it in, but this was avoidable.  If you have a list of packages you need to reinstall (check apt logs) then you can search on AU for [how to install software without an Internet connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline). But honestly you're probably better off to reinstall the system.

Comment: It only said `libssh-4` would be removed. I definitely wouldnt have proceeded if I had seen a lenghtly list of components that I depend on.

Comment: If that's really true, you've discovered an outrageous bug and should file a bug report.

Comment: Then run `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, that did start the network manager! However the wifi and networking settings GUI have also been removed. How can I now configure networking?

Comment: Have you tried to reboot?

Comment: @Magick See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

code worked, then try this:
check which network adapter is from your ethernet (probably "eth0") and see if has an ipaddress.

```
ifconfig
```

If not, then you can do this:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and enter the following two lines:

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet dhcp

Then do CTRL+O and press enter
Then CTRL+X
And use the command below again:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

If it worked you can reinstall your packages again from the internet

But I actually recommend you to just reinstall Ubuntu when possible, because as you say, you don't know which packages are missing, so you can run into trouble later if you miss some important ones.

---

EDIT: as @mchid just commented, you can check the missing packages using

```
sudo nano /var/log/apt/history.log
```

I didn't know that, so I learned some more things today :)

Comment: The missing packages are listed in `/var/log/apt/history.log`

Answer (score 0):

To figure out what was uninstalled, you can run the following command:

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -A3 'apt remove libssh-4' | sed 's/([^)]*)//g;s/,//g'
```

Then, you can either download the deb files from https://packages.ubuntu.com and manually install them

or you should still have networking capabilities through `network-manager`

First, run the following command to start NetworkManager:

```
sudo systemctl start network-manager
```

Then, try running an update command to see if you have networking capabilities (you should have full network capabilities):

```
sudo apt update
```

---

If you don't have a network set up, you can use `nmcli` commands to connect to the network.

First, scan for networks:

```
sudo nmcli device wifi rescan
```

Then, list your available networks by SSID:

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

Finally, use the following command to connect to a network:

```
sudo nmcli device wifi connect SSID password wireless-password
```

and replace "**SSID**" and "**wireless-password**" with the correct parameters

---

Once you have your network up again, you can reinstall the uninstalled packages.

Source: [nullr0ute.com](https://nullr0ute.com/2016/09/connect-to-a-wireless-network-using-command-line-nmcli/)

[Click here for more information.](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html)